# Speed-up BLToolkit startup time

Tags: performance, startup, bltoolkit

Is it possible to speed-up BLToolkit when used for the first time? Right now it takes 3-4 seconds each time I start the application, later on it runs just fine. Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, There is already an issue created for this on GitHub

https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/issues/24

Comment: Yes I have already saw that issue on github, still not clossed. As of my question, do you know is it possible to serialize whatever the BLT is doing behind the scene and reload that on the next application start?

Comment: No sorry, don't have this problem so never looked into that, Sometimes it's a bit slower but my DB is on another contintent so that first connection can take also take some time to get back but I used to have this problem also with ado.net. Anyway since it's initializing in a seperate thread it's not that big of a problem for my users.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated this issue as I have same problems. It appears that BLT is referencing a lot of .NET system libraries which forces the app to load them all on startup, which takes time :(

Comment: Just saw that BLT author will start the new project regarding this issued, hopefully it will not take him too long to finish it :)